# $_REQUEST value appearing in \'value\'

Tags: php

i am trying this to pass a value to the next PHP page:

```
    $("#see_comments").attr({href: "comments.php?aid='"+imgnum+"'"});
```

and in the PHP file I am using:

```
$aid = $_REQUEST[aid];
echo $aid;
```

but this is displaying the output like this:

```
\'9\'
```

why is this happening? 
//9 is the value i am passing.

Comment: Need more info.  Show the HTML so we know what element `#see_comments` references.  Show us where you set `imgnum`.  There's not enough here for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver has [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. They're a terrible thing, and if you can turn them off, I highly recommend you do.

Also, quoting values in your query string is unnecessary. Try this:

```
$("#see_comments").attr({href: "comments.php?aid="+imgnum});
```

Comment: thanks. the quoting in the query string was the problem. that did it. i will try disabling magic quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have magic_quotes enabled in your PHP configuration. Disable that horrible feature now! :P

Answer (score 0):

If the `aid` parameter is supposed to be an integer, why are you using quotes? Why not just write it like this:

```
$("#see_comments").attr({href: "comments.php?aid="+imgnum});
```